# How to get exit code of a parallel process launched by xargs?

Tags: xargs, exit, exit-status

I'd made a script for launching parallel rsync process:

```
#! /bin/bash
LIST=$1
DEST_DIR=$2
RSYNC_OPTS=$3
#echo "rsyncing From=$SRC_DIR To=$DEST_DIR RSYNC_OPTS=$RSYNC_OPTS"
echo $LIST|xargs -n1 -d, echo|xargs -n1 -P 0 -I% rsync --rsync-path='sudo rsync' ${RSYNC_OPTS} % ${DEST_DIR}
```

Then, I have problems to get the exit status of the rsync process. I know that is possible to get an array of pipestatus, but I need to catch the exit code to know if the rsync was made successfully or not.

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23055708/7552

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to know the exact code or just whether it failed or not?

If you use GNU Parallel instead of xargs you can do:

```
echo $LIST | parallel -d, -P 0 rsync --rsync-path='sudo rsync' ${RSYNC_OPTS} {} ${DEST_DIR}
```

When it completes $? will contain how many jobs failed. To get the exact exit code use '--joblog file' to generate a tab separated file including exit code, or use '--halt 1' to get the exit code of the failing rsync in $?.

To learn more:

- Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1
- Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
  will love you for it.